# ¿Cómo unir cuatro tablas no relacionadas mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo cuatro tablas que no son relacionadas entre sí.

Cada columna tiene diferentes nombres y datos excepto la columna `payment`

Las tablas son las siguiente:

**Tabla `ventas1`**

```
id_ventas_so   cliente_software  producto_software   precio_software   payment
    1            Juan Carlos M        Windows              400          pagado
```

**Tabla `ventas2`**

```
id_producto   cliente_pro   producto    registro_pro    precio_pro   payment
     1           Maria       laptop        2018/09         1200       pagado
```

**Tabla `ventas3`**

```
id_libro    cliente_libro    libro    autor_libro    precio_libro   payment
   1            Pedro       Sombras      Anónimo          50         pagado
```

**Tabla `ventas4`**

```
id_suscripcion    usuario_premium    suscripcion    payment
       1               Marcos            40        pendiente
```

De las cuatro tablas, solo necesito mostrar una lista de los clientes con estado de pago confirmado (pagado).

¿Cómo puedo obtener una lista de la siguiente manera, uniendo las tablas que no son relacionadas en una sola consulta?

```
    Cliente        Producto     Autor    Registro    Precio    Estado
Juan Carlos M      Windows                             400     pagado
     Maria         laptop                2018/09      1200     pagado
     Pedro         Sombras     Anónimo                  50     pagado
```

Estoy desarrollando con consultas preparadas orientada a objetos mysqli

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   //Obtener los resultados deseados
}
```

Comment: seria mejor que colocases el diagrama relacional

Comment: Pero ¿ *unirlas*  en qué sentido y para qué ? ¿Bajo qué criterio? Si como dices las tablas no tienen  ninguna relación, ¿para qué quieres unirlas?  ¿Por qué no las consultas las 4 y luego reúnes los resultados de cada una en un array?  Las tablas que se suelen unir son porque efectivamente son tablas relacionales. Si no lo son, mejor consúltalas de forma independiente. Unir 4 tablas independientes puede tener un alto precio si son tablas grandes.

Comment: @A.Cedano Para qué, para hacer los reportes de ventas, unirlas bajo qué criterio, me parece interesante poder unir tablas que son diferentes que no tienen mucho lo relacionado y que unos que otros tienen más columnas y otras menos columnas, siempre se a hablado de unir tablas relacionadas, pero casi nunca sobre las no relacionadas y si existe una forma que mejor que darle ese provecho de aprender.

Comment: Sí, pero en mi comentario abogo por el rendimiento. Cuando usas `UNION` sobre 4 tablas podrias estar trayendo a memoria un ingente conjunto de resultados. Y además es muy probable que tus 4 tablas puedan ponerse en relación , aprovechando así  todas las ventajas que ofrecen las bases de datos relacionales: controlar la redundancia de datos, uso de los índices para agilizar las consultas... Y no digamos nada cuando haya que agrupar datos para cálculos o estadísticas. Uno no debe conformarse nada más con que las cosas funcionen, sino que lo hagan de la mejor manera. Los datos crecen, crecen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que necesitas del operador [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). Lo que este hace es unir en una sola "respuesta" de resultados la ejecución de múltiples sentencias SQL. El "único" requisito importante en tu ejemplo es que tengan el mismo número de columnas, pero dado que puedes re-nombrarlas o crear columnas vacías a tu gusto, puedes utilizar una sentencia como esta:

```
SELECT cliente_software as Cliente, producto_software as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, precio_software as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas1 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT cliente_pro as Cliente, producto as Producto, null as Autor,
registro_pro as Registro, precio_pro as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas2 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT cliente_libro as Cliente, libro as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, precio_libro as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas3 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT usuario_premium as Cliente, null as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, suscripcion as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas4 WHERE payment = 'pagado';
```

Las columnas que no correspondan a la tabla las defines como `null`, y rellenas las que pertenezcan.

Me he tomado la libertad de probarlo en un SQLfiddle que te dejo [en este enlace.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/532c51/1)

Comment: gracias le has dedicado tiempo, viendo el ejemplo en el enlace veo que funciona bien.