# ¿Cómo imprimir resultados desde varias consultas unidas?

Tags: php, mysqli

La siguiente pregunta son consultas no relacionadas de esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179759/c%C3%B3mo-unir-cuatro-tablas-no-relacionadas-mysqli) la cual se ejecuta, se muestra los resultados sin problemas pueden observar la ejecución en [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/532c51/1)

```
SELECT cliente_software as Cliente, producto_software as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, precio_software as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas1 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT cliente_pro as Cliente, producto as Producto, null as Autor,
registro_pro as Registro, precio_pro as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas2 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT cliente_libro as Cliente, libro as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, precio_libro as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas3 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT usuario_premium as Cliente, null as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, suscripcion as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas4 WHERE payment = 'pagado';
```

Me pueden explicar como puedo imprimir los resultados con PHP, con la mismos datos de la consulta escrita.

Como debo plantearlo en el código PHP, para imprimir los resultados, de la misma manera como lo muestra la ejecución [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/532c51/1)

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$pay);
$pay= "pagado";

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result();
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '';
    }
  } else {
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Si decides utilizar `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()` y `mysqli_stmt::fetch()` para recuperar los resultados puedes hacer así:

```
<?php
// preparar consulta
$stmt = $con->prepare("mi consulta");
// vincular parametros de consulta, prescindible ya que tu consulta no tiene parametros
//$pay = "pagado";
//$stmt->bind_param("s",$pay);
// ejecutar consulta
$stmt->execute();
// store_result() necesario para mysqli_stmt::$num_rows
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
  // vincilar variables a columanas de consulta
  $stmt->bind_result($columna1, $columna2 /*[, $columna_n]*/);
  //recorrer las filas 
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $columna1; // mostrar la primera columna (Cliente)
    echo $columna2; // mostrar la segunda columna (Producto)
    }
// sin no hay resultados    
} else {
    echo 'no ha resultados';
}
// cerramos la conexion
$con->close();
```

El hecho de que sea una consulta con uno o más `UNION` es irrelevante para php, ya que mysql lo que devolverá será un único conjunto de resultados, igual que en cualquier otra consulta.

Comment: La idea de la consulta ya la tiene en su estructura tal como lo muestra en su pregunta, lo que el SO, está preguntando es cómo agregar los datos de las varias consulta, a su código para imprimir los resultados como la demostración de las consultas mysqli.

Comment: @IniDesing.com sinceramente no entiendo que me quieres indicar, expuse como mostrar los datos en base al codigo que facilito, realmente el OP solo tiene una unica consulta, es indiferente que esta contega multiples union para obtener y mostrar el resultado.

Comment: Solo has copiado su código PHP, y has comentado que debe hacer, el problema no es ese, el SO indica cómo plantear las varias consulta, es decir las unidades mediante `union`, para mostrar lo mismo resultado como la demostración.

Comment: @IniDesing.com Te refieres a que el OP pregunta com maquetar los datos? porque de su pregunta y el codigo lo que yo entiendo es que no sabe como mostrarlos/obtenerlos, pero pudiera ser que no sabe maquetarlos en una tabla.

Comment: Sí, mirá https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179804/cómo-imprimir-resultados-desde-varias-consultas-unidas-no-relacionadas el SO  a tenido un problemita con la cuenta y ya específico con más detalle su pregunta.