# ¿Cómo imprimir resultados desde varias consultas unidas no relacionadas?

Tags: php, mysqli

En una pregunta anterior sobre cómo obtener resultados de  varías tablas no relacionadas, [publicaron como respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179759/c%C3%B3mo-unir-cuatro-tablas-no-relacionadas-mysqli)  el siguiente código SQL de MYSQLI:

```
SELECT cliente_software as Cliente, producto_software as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, precio_software as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas1 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT cliente_pro as Cliente, producto as Producto, null as Autor,
registro_pro as Registro, precio_pro as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas2 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT cliente_libro as Cliente, libro as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, precio_libro as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas3 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
SELECT usuario_premium as Cliente, null as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, suscripcion as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas4 WHERE payment = 'pagado';
```

> El código SQL de MYSQLI muestra los resultados sin problema a lo que deseaba obtener, pueden comprobar la ejecución en [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/532c51/1)

Me pueden explicar como puedo imprimir los resultados con PHP usando consultas preparadas orientadas a objetos de mysqli, y obtener así los resultados, así como lo muestra la demostración de la consulta SQL de MYSQLI.

Yo sé manejar la impresión de resultados pero en una consulta simple, en este caso, que son varias tablas unidadas como imprimo los resultados.

```
<?php
$stmt = $con->prepare("");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$pay);
$pay= "pagado";

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result();
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '';
    }
  } else {
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Por otra parte he recibido comentario donde especifican que la manera empleada no es la correcta:

> Pero ¿ unirlas en qué sentido y para qué ? ¿Bajo qué criterio? Si como dices las tablas no tienen ninguna relación, ¿para qué quieres unirlas? ¿Por qué no las consultas las 4 y luego reúnes los resultados de cada una en un array? Las tablas que se suelen unir son porque efectivamente son tablas relacionales. Si no lo son, mejor consúltalas de forma independiente. Unir 4 tablas independientes puede tener un alto precio si son tablas grandes. – A. Cedano

Pero las cuatro tablas deben ser individuales, de que manera se pueden relacionarla si son distintas no creo que sea posible unificarlas cuando cada información son muy distintas a cada una de las tablas.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80137/discussion-on-question-by-pedro-como-imprimir-resultados-desde-varias-consultas).

Answer (score 3):

Vamos a clarificar varios conceptos que parecerian estar confundidos:

### Consulta preparada:

Una consulta preparada es una consulta en la cual los parametros se pasan de forma dinamica, y para lo cual, la base de datos "precompila" la consulta, y lo unico que hace es cambiar parametros de ejecucion. No importa como sea la consulta (puede ser tan simple como `select * from A where campo = %param`). Lo importante es que la DB sabe de ante mano como es la consulta, y tambien puede acelerar su ejecucion. En tu caso, no es una consulta preparada.

### 4 tablas para ventas

Sin conocer tu modelo de negocios, suena muy raro tener en una misma base de datos, 4 tablas de ventas que para colmo se "normalizan" en una sola tabla. O sea que si tuvieras 10 negocios tendrias 10 tablas? Algo de ese modelo no cierra, y no es que sean distintos negocios, porque si ese fuera el caso, en general, estan en bases de datos distintas. Aca parece que para ahorrar (o por desconocimiento) se cambian los nombres de columnas, cuando se ve facilmente que en el UNION son el mismo campo.

### Cortes de control

Lo que queres hacer, se puede hacer con algo que se llama cortes de control.
Eso quiere decir, que vas a recorrer los registros uno por uno, hasta que cambie algun condicion (que en este caso no la tenes, ya que vienen tablas distintas..). Y cuando cambia esa condicion, imprimis un corte, y seguis imprimiendo registros.. algo del estilo:

```
registro 1
registro 2
registro 3
corte
registro 4
corte
registro 5
```

### Unir 4 tablas

Esto parece otro modelo incorrecto. Por no simplemente hacer 4 querys e ir impriendo los resultados uno abajo del otro? Cual es el problema con eso?

### Informe

Lo que estas haciendo, en mi opinion, ni siquiera deberia salir de esas tablas. Primero estas tratando de solucionar un problema de vista con un query, y no esta bien. Los problemas de vistas los deben solucionar las vistas. Segundo, tu reporte parece ser general, con lo cual, estas consultando todo el tiempo un monton de datos que problablemente no necesites para generar el mismo. Es muy probable (siempre segun mi opinion) que necesites tener tablas que agrupen esta informacion y te permitan mostrarla de una forma mas rapida.

### Las ventas en una sola tabla

Vos estas seguro que no deberia haber una tabla ventas, y despues los items estar clasificados en categorias? sonaria mas logico y hasta comun una estructura de ese tipo, mas que una tabla por tipo de venta.

### Solucion

Dicho esto, podrias solucionarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT cliente_software as Cliente, producto_software as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, precio_software as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas1 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
select 'corte' as Cliente, '' as Producto, null as Autor, '' as registro, '' as precio, '' as estado
UNION
SELECT cliente_pro as Cliente, producto as Producto, null as Autor,
registro_pro as Registro, precio_pro as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas2 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
select 'corte' as Cliente, '' as Producto, null as Autor, '' as registro, '' as precio, '' as estado
UNION
SELECT cliente_libro as Cliente, libro as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, precio_libro as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas3 WHERE payment = 'pagado'
UNION
select 'corte' as Cliente, '' as Producto, null as Autor, '' as registro, '' as precio, '' as estado
UNION
SELECT usuario_premium as Cliente, null as Producto, null as Autor,
null as Registro, suscripcion as Precio, payment as Estado FROM ventas4 WHERE payment = 'pagado';
```

Y para recorrerlo (en pseudocodigo)

```
mientras haya registros
    Si registro es corte
        imprimir corte
    si no
        imprimir registro
```

Comment: amigo y el código SQL, como se implementa en PHP para imprimir los resultados :(

Comment: Leiste todo lo q escribi o solo buscaste el codigo php? Esta en pseudo lo que tenes que hacer. Si tenes algun problema con la implementacion pregunta.

Comment: a lo mejor para evitar todos esos problemas que has detallado, puede ser una solución crear un buscador con las 4 tablas?

Comment: @gianchi Si leí todo amigo, pero es que me has dado una nuevo código SQL pero sin implementación, ya lo he intentado y me ha dado errores que ya lo comenté ha Xerif?

Comment: Si, la implementacion esta en pseudocodigo. No tengo una implementacion nativa en php. Pero no deberia ser compleja.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no estas teniendo un problema puntual. Estas planteando que no sabes como solucionar algo. Yo no estoy en tu negocio y no puedo darte la solucion exacta que puedas copiar y pegar y listo. Los terminos de implementacion quedan de tu lado. Explique como deberias hacerlo. Y los problemas que se te fueron detallando en todos los comentarios.

Comment: @gbianchi Hasta donde entiendo en su pregunta lo que el SO pregunta o lo que desea es que el código SQL de MySQLi imprima los resultados (corra los resultados) en PHP.