# Agrupar datos en consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla pivote que alacena 3 fk, usuario_id, materia_id y nivel_id..

lo que quiero es agrupar el usuario a una materia y todos los niveles.. en la tabla pivote se almacena asi :

```
|usuario_id|materia_id|nive_id|
|    1     |    1     |   1   |
|    1     |    1     |   2   |
|    1     |    1     |   3   |
|    1     |    1     |   4   |
```

y lo q quiero q se es muestre esto, ejemplo:

**Nombre**:User => **Meteria**:Biologia =>**Niveles**: 7-A, 7-B, 7-C, 7-D

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo el script. Ya lo probé y funciona, pero de todos modos me avisas cualquier cosa. Saludos!

**Edición:** Te voy explicando los pasos o lo que hice para que quede mas claro.

Primero que nada debes hacer tu consulta con [SQL INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) . Con esto  lograras obneter los campos "nombre" en vez del ID. Hasta aqui no agrupamos solo mostramos los datos de forma repetitiva, en cuanto a la columna "niveles". Ahora lo importante es usar [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html). Esta funcion es la que nos permite agrupar y concatenar los niveles. Finalmente hace uso de [SQL GROUP BY Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp). Esto ultimo es muy importante sino no te va a mostrar todos los usuarios. Espero que haya quedado claro, sino puedes hacer tus consultas o leer los link que te deje. Saludos!

```
select u.nombre as Nombre,  m.nombre as Materia, group_concat(distinct n.nombre) as Niveles  from pivote p
inner join usuarios u on p.usuario_id = u.id
inner join materias m on p.materia_id = m.id
inner join niveles n on p.nivel_id = n.id

group by u.nombre, m.nombre;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Fran, gracias por responder. Pero en vez de dejar el scritp solo, explica su funcionamiento para que el OP y futuros usuarios lo entiendan mejor. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Gracias por la sugerencia. Ya edite la pregunta, explicando en lo posible y dejando info de lo que se usó. Saludos!

Comment: excelente @FranIslas me funciono a la perfeccion..  saludos!.

Answer (score -1):

tendrás que usar **INNER JOIN**, para unir las tablas; y **DISTINCT** para los datos repetidos.

Comment: ya he probado de todo, pero no hayo como resolverlo.. la cabeza no me da.

Comment: mira este enlace, a ver si te vale   [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179759/c%C3%B3mo-unir-cuatro-tablas-no-relacionadas-mysqli]

Comment: Hola my crazy, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Las respuestas tienen que tener  más informacion y si el enlace que propones para más informacion, es de este mismo sitio, considera si la pregunta deberia cerrarse como duplicada. Mira [answer] para más info.  Un saludo